# How to add Hyperlink in the AD AD B2C SignUp Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In our Sign Up policy (no custom UI), I need to provide a hyperlink to our company policies as one of the attributes.

I am not going to build any custom UI, is it possible to include Hyperlinks in the TrustFrameworkPolicy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not allowed with a custom policy, since it renders strings as literals not as HTML, so you must use a custom UI for this.