# Forgot Username and Forgot Password in Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am new to Azure AD B2C custom policies. I need some guidance on how do we add Forgot Username and Forgot Password hyperlink in custom policy? I have tried with Localization String IDs, but somehow not able to achieve it. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, your question is not a great fit for SO. Please take some time to take the [tour] and refer to [ask]. On-topic: see [Set up a password reset flow in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow)

Comment: @rickvdbosch, appreciate your prompt reply and suggestion. Do you have some suggestions for Forgot Username like how can I add the hyperlink in the custom policy so that it appears in the login flow. My current approach is using it as a Sub-Journey but I am not able to present the hyperlink of it in the user journey.

Comment: Hi @AmitMondal, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572779/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-the-ad-ad-b2c-signup-policy

Adding a new link is not possible, you can use custom UI for this or change the forgot password link text and customize the flow to accommodate both password reset and user name retrieval.